# Prolog: extract a single list from a list of pairs

Tags: lambda, prolog

I have a list of pairs: [{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}]

How can I extract the second element of each pair and make that a separate list?

So: [a,b,c,d]

Sorry, I am new to Prolog, and had a look around for the answer, but could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have shown is not a list of pairs. This is:

```
[1-a, 2-b, 3-c, 4-d].
```

With this list you can do:

```
?- pairs_values([1-a, 2-b, 3-c, 4-d], V).
V = [a, b, c, d].

?- pairs_keys([1-a, 2-b, 3-c, 4-d], K).
K = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

And a predicate that does is explicitly:

```
seconds([], []).
seconds([_A-B|Pairs], [B|Secs]) :-
    seconds(Pairs, Secs).
```

if you insist, of course:

```
secs([], []).
secs([{_A, B}|Pairs], [B|Secs]) :-
    secs(Pairs, Secs).
```

But you can decide for yourself what works best, just keep in mind:

```
?- write_canonical({1,a}).
{}(','(1,a))
true.

?- write_canonical(1-a).
-(1,a)
true.
```

Good material on Prolog, among others:

- Amzi Inc. Adventure in Prolog (web)
- Learn Prolog Now! (web)
- "The Art of Prolog", Sterling and Shapiro (book).

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. You're right, [1-a, 2-b, 3-c, 4-d] is what I wanted. Btw, thanks for the references.

Answer (score 2):

With SWI-Prolog only, you can do

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
extract_second(In, Out) :-
    maplist(\X^Y^(X = {_,Y}), In, Out).
```

You can get library(lambda) there : http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/pack/lambda-1.0.0.tgz

Comment: The definition given [here](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord#implementation) works in any conforming Prolog system - including SICStus!